# Why doesn't Ubuntu have an hourglass to tell you when programmes are launching?

Tags: startup

I'm still new to Ubuntu and using a very modest netbook to which Ubuntu adapts very well. However, it took me a while to realise that it took just a single click to launch programmes because nothing happened for twenty seconds! Surely there is an option to show something that tells me "wait, I'm working as hard as I can"?

Comment: If you are using unity, dash will show an icon and the icon blinks (kind of, I don't have better word)  to notify you the program is launching.

Comment: I will train my beady eyes more closely, thanks! Yes, that works, at least with Rhyhmbox.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 14.4, it's even clearer as the change in tone/colour of the icons is much more obvious!